# Can't make Gulp work with React and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp

I built an Express-app with an 'create-react-app' in a client folder. To make the proxy work, I added '"`proxy": "http:localhost:3001"`' to my package.json in the client-folder. The code below shows the package.json in the root. "npm run dev" should run everything.

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "PORT=3001 nodemon ./bin/www",
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client \""
  },
```

Now I want to add the following command `PORT=3000 gulp` to make Gulp work, but I'm not sure if this is the right way. I tried this so far but it gives me the message " Something is already running on port 3000."

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "PORT=3001 nodemon ./bin/www",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "gulp": "PORT=3000 gulp",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client \" \"npm run gulp \""
  },
```

**EDIT:**
The browser should refresh when a file (each file in the folder root) is saved.

```
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const reload = browserSync.reload;

// Logs Message
gulp.task('message', function(){
  return console.log('Gulp is running...');
});

// Start BrowserSync
gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
  console.log("test");
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'http://localhost:3000'
  })
});

gulp.task('default', ['message', 'browser-sync', 'watch']);

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('*').on("change", reload);
});
```

Comment: I think you could change "cd client && Npm start" to "npm start --prefix client". Also can you please edit to provide more information. What does "gulp" do? From my experience you need to append something, for example "gulp watch," depending on what's in the gulpfile.js

Comment: See my updated question @Leafyshark

Comment: hope this helps: https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/React-Express-boilerplate it doesn't use gulp though